# Cannot create test suite for Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing

I'm having trouble creating a test suite in Django 1.3.

Say I have an installed app in a directory called `app_name`. One of the files in that directory is `foo.py` which defines a class named `Foo`. I want to test that, so I also have a file that directory called `foo_test.py` which defines a class named `FooTest`. That file looks like:

```
import unittest
import foo

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.foo_instance = foo.Foo()

  ... etc
```

Now down the line I'll have other test cases in other files, and I'll want to run them all as part of a test suite. So in the same directory `app_name` I created a file `tests.py` which will define the suite. At first I defined it like:

```
import foo_test

from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner

def suite():
  runner = DjangoTestSuiteRunner()
  return runner.build_suite(['app_name'])
```

Unfortunately, this fails because calling `runner.build_suite(['app_name'])` searches `app_name` for a `tests.py` file, executes `suite()`, and this continues recursively until the Python interpreter stops everything for exceeding the maximum recursion depth.

Changing `runner.build_suite(['app_name'])` to

```
runner.build_suite(['app_name.foo_test'])
```

or

```
runner.build_suite(['app_name.foo_test.FooTest'])
```

leads to errors like `ValueError: Test label 'app_name.foo_test' does not refer to a test`.

And changing it to:

```
runner.build_suite(['foo_test'])
```

or

```
runner.build_suite(['foo_test.FooTest'])
```

leads to errors like `App with label foo_test could not be found`.

I'm kind of out of ideas at this point. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the [Python documentation for organizing tests](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#organizing-tests), and use one of the alternative methods there to build your test suite. Incidentally, none of the recommended methods employ `build_suite`.